# Error while using python classes

Tags: python, python-2.7, class, oop

I am facing some error while using classes in python 2.7

My class definition is:

```
class Timer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = ""

    def start(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.start = time.time()

    def stop(self):
        t = time.time() - self.start
        return self.msg, " => ", t, 'seconds'
```

On executing the following code.

```
timer = Timer()
timer.start("Function 1")
Some code
timer.stop()

timer.start('Function 2')
some code
timer.stop()
```

I am getting following error:

```
Function 1 => 0.01 seconds
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'float' object is not callable
```

For the first call it worked as desired but for the second call, it gave an error. I am unable to figure out the cause of the error.

Comment: `t = time.time() - self.start` looks wrong. `self.start` is a function.

Comment: Yeah you are right thanks

Comment: `self.start = time.time()` is also wrong

Comment: Yeah that is the only problem

Comment: @sv_jan5 I think I understood the issue now! Let me know

Comment: Yeah, I got it thanks for asking. It was a silly mistake :P

Comment: @sv_jan5 no problem, I tried to go arrownd all the posibilities so you can get a complete answer for the issue, hope that helped ;)

Comment: @sv_jan5 also, the question was a very valid one, +1 for it, I liked to find the issue haha

Comment: @DamianLattenero such mistakes are really interesting to resolve :)

Comment: @sv_jan5 indeed! I actually edited again my answer so it can be now finally right and complete

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you write `self.start = time.time()`, you replace the function `start()` with a variable named `start`, which has a float value. The next time you write `timer.start()`, start is a float, and you are trying to call it as a function. Just replace the name `self.start` with something else.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that you are using the same name for a method and for an attribute.

I would refactor it like this:

```
class Timer(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.msg = ""
        self.start_time = None #I prefer to declare it but you can avoid this

    def start(self,msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.start_time = time.time()

    def stop(self):
        t = time.time() - self.start_time
        return self.msg, " => ", t, 'seconds'
```

Answer (score 0):

I think now I understood your question and error, the following correct your issue:

```
import time

class Timer(object):

  def __init__(self):
      self.msg = ""

  def start(self,msg):
      self.msg = msg
      self.start = time.time() # Here, your method name is the same has the variable name
```

If you rename the variable name, you have to remember to call first the start method so the start_value variable exists:

```
import time

class Timer(object):

  def __init__(self):
      self.msg = ""

  def start(self,msg):
      self.msg = msg
      self.start_value = time.time() #Is you change the variable name, the problem is solved

  def stop(self):
      t = time.time() - self.start_value
      return self.msg, " => ", t, 'seconds'


a = Timer()
a.start("first call")
print a.stop()

>> ('first call', ' => ', 1.9073486328125e-06, 'seconds')
```

but if you don't call the method and just do:

```
a = Timer()
# a.start("first call") without it
print a.stop()
```

the variable `start` will never exist, wich throws to you the error:

```
AttributeError: 'Timer' object has no attribute 'start_value'
```

I hope that helps!